# How to change scrolling behaviour when resizing window in WPF/XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, horizontal-scrolling

## Research

Currently when working with WPF/XAML, the default scrolling behaviour for the scroll bar is that the VerticalScrollBarVisibility = Visible and the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = Auto. This means the vertical scroll bar is always visible while the horizontal scroll bar is only visible is the content extends outside the width of the allocated area. Note that while the scrollbar is Visible, if the content do not extend beyong their allocated space, the scroll is deactivated and do not take any user input.

You may change this by changing the values to Visible, Auto, Hidden, or Disabled:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = "Auto">
   ...
</ScrollViewer>
```

## Problem

The problem is if you resize the window of the application and make it smaller, the scroll bars do not react as it should. It seems to just get cut off at the edges as I make the window smaller and smaller. The horizontal scrollbar is never activated. I then made the horizontal scrollbar visible just to see what happens. But it never changes to its active form when I make the windows smaller.

Can I assume that the scrollbar only activates when the content of the allocated space becomes to large for the space and not when the space is reduced when resizing the application window? If so does anyone know a way around this?

## Edit

So I was working with my code and I realize that the scroll bar for the main window works as it should when the window is resized but that is not what I want. My main application window consists of three dock panels. Each of these panels needs to have its own scrollbars. It seems that when i resize the main window, the main window's scrollbars activate as appropriate but not the individual section's scrollbars. What I want to do is disable the main windows scroll bar altogether and have only the individual section's scrollbar work.

Comment: I think it matters how you're laying out the window. Can you post the simplest case's working XAML so we can take a look?

Comment: Is the content inside your ScrollViewer resizing with the Window size changed? For the ScrollViewer to activate it's ScrollBar, the content inside it has to exceed the ViewPort size.